# Listening for keydown / keypress events and differentiate between one and two digit numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using an eventListener to detect numeric options in my vue app:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      switch (e.key) {
        case 1:
          // do stuff
          break;
        case 2:
          // do other stuff
      }
}
```

Since I have more than 9 options, I was wondering what the most sensible way would be to differentiate if the user is entering a one or two digit numer (e.g., `1` vs `11`)?

Comment: It can be done ... **but** ... One needs to define a threshold value for two successive digit related keystrokes in order to distinguish in between a single and a double digit number. How does one justify such a decision especially since every user might react / adapt differently to this limitation of freedom?

Comment: Have you defined a way to separate the options? The enter key pressed, a sufficient time interval, or something else?

Comment: Also, what has the OP in mind of how to handle (successive) tripple, quadruple (, and so on) digit keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adapting the solution described in this [blog post](https://schier.co/blog/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-using-javascript), by pushing all keystrokes into an array, which is cleared if there is no input after 1 sec.

```
    let keys = [];
    let timeout = null;

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      
      keys.push(e.key);
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          let input = parseInt(keys.join(""));
 
            switch (input) {
              case 1:
                // do stuff
                break;
              case 11:
                // do other stuff

          }          
          keys = [];  
      }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Maybe the OP considers presenting the ad**a**pted final solution, especially the "digit only" handling part since the above example code doesn't provide a solution to the originally asked question.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is doing an implicit type conversion since `e.key` is a string, and the switch case specifiers are numbers. If you don't have more than 35 options, using base 36 digits ('1'-'9' and 'a'-'z') could be the easiest solution, in conjunction with constructing the switch statement along the lines of

```
  switch( e.key.toLowerCase() {
  case '1':  ... break;
  .
  .
  .
  case 'z':  ... break;
  }
```

I would hesitate before telling users they must hit a second digit within 500ms and wait that long before the first key they hit is recognized. :-)